# After recursion I got an Error (TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable)

Tags: python, python-requests, typeerror, nonetype

I'm trying `request.get()` with proxies and I use `try/except`.
If my proxy is wrong, I use `except`, changing proxy and starting this function again.

After recursion I got all needed values and

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

And I have no idea why?

P.S.: If the code works without calling Except, it works perfectly

```
def get_html_v2(url, proxy, userAgent):
    data = None
    status = None
    userAgent = userAgent or ''
    proxies = {
        "http": "http://"+proxy,
        "https":"http://"+proxy
    }
    try:
        # Get request
        response = requests.get(url=url, headers=userAgent, proxies=proxies)
        # Get a status of the request
        status = response.status_code
        # Return request values and status
        return response.text, int(status)
    # If proxy doesn't work
    except ConnectionError:
        # Remove wrong proxy from List
        proxiesList.remove(proxy)
        # Get new proxy
        proxy = random.choice(proxiesList)
        # Start function again
        get_html_v2(url, userAgent=userAgent, proxy=proxy)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear where the error is occurring, since the code above doesn't include any iteration. Would be better to include that section of the error.

Anyway, the error is *probably* occurring due to `get_html_v2` in your `except` block. You *calling* `get_html_v2()` in the except block but not ***return**ing* that result to the caller/previous loop of recursion, which you must do anyway, especially with recursion.

In the last line for your `except` block, replace:

```
 get_html_v2(url, userAgent=userAgent, proxy=proxy)
```

with:

```
 return get_html_v2(url, userAgent=userAgent, proxy=proxy)
```

That way, you're effectively returning the value returned from the line `return response.text, int(status)` in your `try` block.

> P.S.: If the code works without calling Except, it works perfectly

When the `except` block gets called, since there's no `return`, it implicitly returns `None`. When it doesn't get called, it's returning `response.text, int(status)`

Comment: Wrt _"It's unclear where the error is occurring"_: Probably while processing the tuple `(response.text, int(status))` returned in the `try` block, so your code expects all return values to be a tuple, and not `None`.

Comment: thanks a lot! this works!

return get_html_v2(url, userAgent=userAgent, proxy=proxy)